# Random Number Generator freezing

Tags: c++

I have a program that I made that picks a random number for a port to receive a UDP packet on. The program seeds the rand function using some data from /dev/random. I loop through getting data 4 times to get a sufficient amount of data for srand.

This is the code that I use to generate the data for srand.

```
FILE *random_file = fopen("/dev/random","r");

std::string random_seed_str;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int seed_element = getc(random_file);
    std::string element_string = std::to_string(seed_element);
    random_seed_str += element_string;
}

int random_seed = stoi(random_seed_str);

srand( random_seed );
```

Now this works fine if I am running my program from the commandline one at a time. But when I start to use it in the application we designed it for, the program starts to randomly freeze at this line:

```
int seed_element = getc(random_file);
```

The application running it runs the program at random intervals and run's the programs in parallel (Upto 12 instances at a time).

The only thing I can think it causing it is if two instances of the same program try to access /dev/random via getc at the same time and it stalls.

I can't use seconds to act as my seed as, because it is running many instances of the program at the same time, I have had many programs collide by generating the same random numbers.

Is there any better way to get randomness?

Comment: Any reason why you need to use `random` instead of `urandom`?

Comment: Try `fclose(random_file)` after you are done reading from it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Just tried that, no change.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel No particular reason. Would it work better in this scenario?

Comment: Why are you using `/dev/random` at all? You could just use [`std::time(0)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time) as the seed instead, that is the most common use of `srand()`. Or better, use the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library introduced in C++11, you really shouldn't be using `rand()` at all in modern C++

Comment: You don't need any of this. Throw it all away and bind the socket to port zero, and then use `getsockname()` to find out what port the operating system gave you.

Comment: `fread` drains all randomness from `/dev/random` because it is buffered IO and reads as much as it can even if you extract only 3 bytes with `getc`. If you really have to, use plain `read` of single bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<random>` module of the standard library:

```cpp
#include <random> //import random module
std::random_device rd; //use a random device to seed
std::default_random_engine re; //use a random engine to generate random bytes
re.seed(rd()); //seed the random engine
re(); //now use the random bytes, you can also instantiate a distribution to have values following a specific distribution.
```

Comment: He doesn't need to use any RNG at all.

Answer (score -1):

Using c++ random's header.
Also add a distribution that controls how numbers are distributes (eg. normal, standard etc.).

```
#include <random>

// get 'entropy' from device that generates random numbers itself
// to seed a mersenne twister (pseudo) random generator
std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());

// setup a distribution from 0 to 10 
// in this case equal chance for all numbers.
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,10);

int main()
{
    // generate a random value between 0 and 10
    int value = distribution(generator);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need to use any RNG at all.